# Delete items that occur an odd number of times in a list

Tags: prolog

I have written code including count function that calculates how many times elements occurs in list, then I have function that go through all array and deletes the elements that occur odd number of times. But I got problem, an warning telling me "Arithmetic: `element_count' is not a function".
What is wrong and how to fix it?

```
countX([],_,0).
countX([X|T], X, P1) :- countX(T, X, P), P1 is P+1.
countX([H|T], X, P) :- H=\=X, countX(T, X, P).

goal([], []).
goal(Start, Result):-
    remove_odd_count_numbers(Start, Start, Result).

remove_odd_count_numbers(_, [], []).
remove_odd_count_numbers(Start, [A|List], Result):-
    count(Start, A, count_element),
    count_element mod 2 =:= 0,
    remove_odd_count_numbers(Start, List, Result), !.

remove_odd_count_numbers(Start, [Head|Tail], [Head|TailResult]):- 
    remove_odd_count_numbers(Start, Tail, TailResult), !.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
count(Start, A, count_element),
count_element mod 2 =:= 0,
```

Variable names cannot start with lowercase letters in Prolog. You need `Count_element`. (At least that; it may not be enough to make it work).